# Using XML::Simple for retrieving data in Perl

Tags: perl, xml-simple

I've created the below `XML` file for retrieving data.

**Input:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<ExecutionLogs>
    <category cname='Condition1' cid='T1'>
        <log>value1</log>
        <log>value2</log>
        <log>value3</log>
    </category>
    <category cname='Condition2' cid='T2'>
        <log>value4</log>
        <log>value5</log>
        <log>value6</log>
    </category>
        <category cname='Condition3' cid='T3'>
        <log>value7</log>
    </category>
</ExecutionLogs>
```

I want the output like below,

```
Condition1 -> value1,value2,value3
Condition2 -> value4,value5,value6
Condition3 -> value7
```

I have tried the code below,

```
use strict;
use XML::Simple;
my $filename = "input.xml";
$config = XML::Simple->new();
$config = XMLin($filename);
@values = @{$config->{'category'}{'log'}};
```

Please help me on this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should describe the problem you are facing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I would do :

```
use strict; use warnings;
use XML::Simple;
my $config = XML::Simple->new();
$config = XMLin($filename, ForceArray => [ 'log' ]);
#   we want an array here  ^---------------------^ 

my @category = @{ $config->{'category'} };
#              ^------------------------^
# de-reference of an ARRAY ref  

foreach my $hash (@category) {
    print $hash->{cname}, ' -> ', join(",", @{ $hash->{log} }), "\n";
}
```

#### OUTPUT

```
Condition1 -> value1,value2,value3
Condition2 -> value4,value5,value6
Condition3 -> value7
```

#### NOTE

`ForceArray => [ 'log' ]` is there to ensure treating same types in `{category}->[@]->{log]`
unless that, we try to dereferencing an `ARRAY` ref on a string for the last `"Condition3"`.

Check [XML::Simple#ForceArray](https://metacpan.org/pod/XML::Simple#ForceArray-1-in---important)

and

- [perldoc perlreftut](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlreftut.html)
- [perldoc ref](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/ref.html)
- [perldoc perlref](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlref.html)

Answer (score 4):

A way to do this using XML::Twig:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use XML::Twig;

XML::Twig->new( twig_handlers => { 
                   category => sub { print $_->att( 'cname'), ': ', 
                                           join( ',', $_->children_text( 'log')), "\n";
                               },
                },
              )

         ->parsefile( 'my.xml');
```

The handler is called each time a `category` element has been parsed. `$_` is the element itself.